# JQuery .load() not working when rendered from an XSL file

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xslt

I have an HTML file:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>orientation test</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="code.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('HI');
        go();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="oriented">HI</div>
</body>
</html>
```

A javascript file "code.js":

```
function go() {
    try {
        alert(1);
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#oriented").load("data.html #orient", function (response, status, xhr) {
                alert(2);
                if (status == "error") {
                    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                    alert(msg);
                }
                else {
                    try {
                        alert($("#oriented").html());
                    }
                    catch (err) { alert(err); }
                }
            });
        });
    } catch (err) { alert('err: ' + err); }
}

var a = setInterval("go();", 3000);
alert('BYE');
```

An XSL file "main.xsl":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:msws="http://tempuri.org/"
    >

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
        <title>orientation test</title>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js">
          <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        </script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="code.js">
          <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        </script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
          alert('HI');
          go();
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="oriented">HI</div>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

An an XML file to launch the XSL file with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="feed.xsl"?>
<Results xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <Status>OK</Status>
  <Result>
    <FeedDTO>
    </FeedDTO>
  </Result>
</Results>
```

And a file to be read in "data.html":

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="orient">OFF</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the obligatory jquery min file version 1.6.4 .js, which I won't bother showing here.

I have found that when the "main.html" file is run in Firefox 7.0.1 the `alert(2);` in the "go()" function never fires. Previously, I thought this was only happening when the main.xml was rendered, but I see that this is not necessarily the case, now.

I need this JQuery to load the content of the data.html file and place it into the content of a div within the current page, whether the current page is rendered from XSL/XML or not.

How do I ensure that the $.load() executes properly? There are no errors being shown by the try...catch.

Also, I need this work to with local files and ultimately this code will be executing as local files on an iPhone.

Comment: Don't you need `$(function(){});` or `$(document).ready(function(){});` to fire off jQuery?

Comment: I've made the appropriate modification, but now the $.load() does not fire when loading the XML file and transforming it with the XSL file. Running it within the main.html seems to work fine.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it with Firebug (or similar)

Comment: Yes, there are no messages at all in the "All" tab.

Comment: I had suspected, from other test files I have, that it was the fact that the JQuery was being launched from a page produced by an XSL file, but this pretty much proves it, I think. I just don't know why or how to fix/get around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it appears that this is not going to be solved soon. If there is an answer I've not found it.

I have, though, found a work around...

I placed an iframe (styled to be completely hidden) and created an interval to refresh the 'src' attribute of the iframe with a random value to the single argument of the src url. Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function reloadFrame()
{
 var t = Math.random();
 $("#loader").attr("src","updatepage.html?t="+t);
}

var a = setInterval("reloadFrame();", 1000);
</script>

<iframe id="loader" src="" style="position: absolute; visibility: none;" />
```

The code above reloads the iframe once a second. The URL is effectively different because of the random value of the 't' parameter, causing the browser to make the actual request to the server/local file, rather than ignoring it based on matching the URL of the previous iframe src load.